# Why is my ITexthandler not working? I'm trying to parse XML into ITextSharp doc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

I’m using Visual Developer 2010, MVC 3, c#. I’m trying to parse XML into an iTextSharp document like this:

```
        ITextHandler textHandler = new ITextHandler(doc);
        textHandler.Parse(xmldoc);
```

The error message says ITextHandler is not in this context.  How can I make this work?  Or is there another constructor that will do the same thing?

Here’s my list of using statements:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

Everything else seems to compile properly except for the ITextHandler line.  Please help.

Comment: What version of ITextSharp are you using?

Comment: I'm probably missing something but I don't see anything in the [ITextSharp code repository]() that resembles ITextHandler. Perhaps this method of extending ITextSharp is no longer supported?

Comment: Yes I just noticed this myself.  I do see iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.  I haven't seen any examples on using it yet though... I'll keep looking.

Comment: I thought you were trying to parse XML not PDF?

Comment: Yes I am trying to parse an xml to an iTextSharp document then to PDF.  That's the general idea but as a newbie I don't quite know how to view a librarry and use it properly.  Do you know tutorial that may help with the current version of iTextSharp or just a simple way to convert my mcv3 to a pdf document?

Comment: You're trying to create a PDF based on your rendered MVC3 page? Wouldn't a ITextSharp HTML to PDF tutorial help you more than XML to PDF?

Comment: HTML to PDF would be great but I'm following a tutorial that converts XML to PDF.  I couldn't find one that does an HTML conversion that I could easily impliment.  Any ideas?

Comment: Something like [this](http://robrobertson.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/dynamic-itextsharp-pdf-documents/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ITextHandler` is part of iText and iTextSharp 4.x series but was removed from the 5.x series in favor of `iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser`. In recent months, however, another project has been gaining favor for XML and HTML parsing. Most, if not all XML and HTML work going forward is being done in the separate library `xmlworker` [found here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/). With in that library you'll find the `iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser` class.

Comment: Thanks, what id did here was un-install both iTextSharp and itextsharp (note the case).  That seem too have done it.