# Issue with itextsharp 5.4 while converting XML to PDF

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, itext

I am using following code to convert and XML into PDF by using itextsharp 5.4

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("ExampleDoc.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            ITextHandler xmlHandler = new ITextHandler(document);
            xmlHandler.Parse("ExampleDoc.xml");
}
```

I am getting error in line `ITextHandler xmlHandler = new ITextHandler(document);`

Errro is: missing directive or assembly reference

I have come to know that `ITextHandler` in no longer supported in `itextsharp 5.4.` So what should I do instead of that? I did not get any solid answer for this anywhere on net. Please suggest.

OR, Should I convert xml to html and then that html to pdf?

Comment: I still don't understand what "convert XML to PDF" actually means. What would your final PDF look like? Do you want your literal XML in the PDF as just a string? Do you want a table? Please post an example of what you actually want it to look like and we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Looks like ITextHandler was removed in version 5.4, use SimpleXmlParser instead. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874979/why-is-my-itexthandler-not-working-im-trying-to-parse-xml-into-itextsharp-doc).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to work with iTextSharp but I invite you to use [DoddleReport](http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/) generator

[See it live!](http://doddlereport.azurewebsites.net/Doddle/productreport.pdf)

DoddleReport generates tabular reports from any IEnumerable datasource and you can render reports to Excel, PDF, HTML, and CSV – fully pluggable of course