# from XML to pdf itextsharp ver 5 series

Tags: xml, pdf, xml-parsing, itext

I have tried to create a PDF document from XML one using itextsharp ver 4 series and it worked fine 
It was really simple as the following

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("XXX.pdf", FileMode.Create));            
ITextHandler xmlHandler = new ITextHandler(document);            
xmlHandler.Parse("YYY.xml");
```

When I did an upgrade to itextsharp ver. 5 series i knew that ITextHandler has been removed, instead we can use the independent lib iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser like the answer 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874979/why-is-my-itexthandler-not-working-im-trying-to-parse-xml-into-itextsharp-doc)

but actually I couldn't use the XMLParser class

any ideas?

Comment: it's not possible (easily). lots of methods have been changed and the new API is not backward compatible.

Comment: @VahidN So you have any idea about how to do the same functionality using version 5 of itextsharp?

Comment: It's better to use its new XMLWorker. It's able to convert CSS+HTML to PDF. http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/